# How to find extreme points from set of contours in an image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find the boundaries/extreme points in a given multiple set of contours in an image,i.e.. top-left point of top-left contour, top-right point of top-right contour ...
please refer the example image: [input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aesHt.jpg)
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meg6o.jpg)

As seen in image, I am trying to extract the corner points
I started with blue color, successfully extracted blue color mask.
now I stuck at extracting top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right points.

I tried some thing:

```
lower = [9999, 9999, 9999, 9999]
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if lower[0] > x != 0:
        lower[0] = x
    if lower[1] > y != 0:
        lower[1] = y
    if lower[2] > w != 0:
        lower[2] = w
    if lower[3] > h != 0:
        lower[3] = h
```

If I use logic like this, I will get Top-left corner and Bottom-right corner.
how to get the other 2 corners : top-right and bottom-left.

Please help me out!

Comment: if you have blue masks coordinates, all you have to do is find Min/Max wich is straightforward.  try to explain clearly what is the problem in your case

Comment: The simplest way is to store masks coordinates in a list of points and pass them to  cv2.minAreaRect(ListOfPoints) .

Comment: @Ziri Have a look at the desired output. Actually wanted are the corner points of the large (warped) quadrilateral described by the small blue rectangles. That's something different than finding the extreme points of all (upright) blue rectangles (contours).

Comment: @HansHirse thanks for describing it simple,if i use something like this `lower = [9999, 9999, 9999, 9999]
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for contour in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if lower[0] > x != 0:
        lower[0] = x
    if lower[1] > y != 0:
        lower[1] = y
    if lower[2] > w != 0:
        lower[2] = w
    if lower[3] > h != 0:
        lower[3] = h`  I may get top-left, bottom-right,but how to get other 2